# How would you secure text in iPhone app made in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, security

Could you tell me how would you secure a text file in iPhone app? Let's say you write a text in the app. I would like it to be secured, so even if you have access to the device you still need to enter a specific pin to be able to display the text. I don't want the text to be available on iCloud, only in the specific app itself. Are there any easy and secure ways to do it? I'm total newbie and I will really appreciate any answer :) Have a nice one!

Comment: Add login panel in your app. and before user access the text just take the password from it and check that password from you DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encrypt the file before saving it to local file system using single key encryption algorithms. Ask the user to enter the key while decrypting, use the key to decrypt and show it :)

**How to do it ?**

So when user creates/edits a file, create it in temp folder of your app bundle. Content in this folder is not backed up by iCloud and kept temporarily hence the name temp folder :)

Once he is done with editing it, save it in document directory of your app bundle. But because the content in this file can be viewed using third party apps or can be backed up by iCloud, encrypt it before saving it to local document directory.

**Which algorithm to use ?**

Depends on your requirement. I don't think you need Private and Public Key encryptions looking at your requirement. You can make use of any single key encryption algorithms. I have used https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor
and it works pretty well. Try it

Happy coding

Comment: Sandeep, thank you for your help and answer :) Have a nice day and happy coding... after great weekend :)

Comment: @maciej : Always welcome buddy :) Please consider accepting the answer if it helped you